# CSS3 Transition not working in Chrome anymore

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, css-transitions

As far as I can remember, I didn't have any problems with the CSS3 transitions working for me, until now. Suddenly (possibly because of a chrome update or other modifications to my code) it has just stopped working in chrome (32.0.1700.77), but still works in all other browsers (and an older version of chrome).

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1325px) {
    .row-offcanvas {
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
        transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
        width: 100%;
    }

    button.toggle {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .row-offcanvas-left,
    .sidebar-offcanvas {
        left: -239px;
        z-index: 9999;
        height: 700px;
    }
    .row-offcanvas-left.active {
        left: 239px;
    }
    .sidebar-offcanvas {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 239px;
    }
}
```

I haven't made any changes to this part of the site and I can't explain why it might not work all of a sudden. The transition is for a panel which slides out when a button is clicked, triggered by this bit of javascript (not responsible for the animation).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: [Chrome doesn't require `-webkit-` prefixes anymore](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions). Apart from that, no functionality was changed. Both your JS and CSS are missing some curlies and parentheses though. Are there any warnings or errors in console log? Unrecognized properties in the DOM inspector?

Comment: @412 that would be a typo during my copy/paste. My apologies.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes the missing braces and parentheses are just copy/paste typos. As far as functionality, the JS executes (it triggers the active class as it should, opening the panel). The only strange part is the transition suddenly not working.

Comment: We need more code than this - you didn't even include the `.active` CSS definition. Also, feel free to share a link when all relevant code is also here, it is not allowed to ask link-only questions but you can add a link if it's additional, and in this case I don't see how to help without it.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I've added all the relevant code above, now. Just figured it wouldn't have anything to do with the problem. I'll attempt to get a JS fiddle together, the actual code is behind an authenticated portion of the site on a dev server.

Comment: When did it work? When did it stop working? Also, Chrome does a great job in the `Elements` panel of showing you what CSS properties are applied to an element, including invalid property names or values. Have you checked what Chrome tells you?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to animate from an undefined property: you are changing `left` to `239px`, but don't explicitly specify it as `0` initially. It therefore defaults to `auto`, a value for which there is no valid smooth transition to `239px`.

Add `left:0` to the base definition and you will be fine.

[See a JSfiddle here demonstrating your problem in Chrome 32+](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/j37Qn/).

Comment: Your JSFiddle shows both bars moving at the same time, I'm using Chrome 31. Also I have done this in the past without issue, animating from a default value (which is `auto` in this case).

Comment: He states he is working in Chrome 32 beta, which I am also running, and where only one of them is animating - he also states it used to work before, and I am aware that this used to work, but this is actually a fix in v32 towards better standards compliance. You are correct on the default value, fixed that.

Comment: this answer actually seemed to resolve the issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: Right you are, I updated Chrome and I can confirm your findings in Chrome 32.

Comment: For me it works BUT animation starts after ONE MINUTE. So calm - just wait. ;-) Version Nr 40.0.2214.94