# CSS transition not working in chrome, works briefly when a property is toggled

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, css-transitions, css-animations

I have the following css animations, which works the way I want it to on safari but not on chrome. square0 is a div which changes color when hovered over, slowly fading back to the original color after the mouse is moved. In Chrome, the div immediately goes blank if not being hovered over.

I looked at this question, 
[CSS3 Transition not working in Chrome anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125587/css3-transition-not-working-in-chrome-anymore), and added the background-color field. This didn't immediately change anything, but when I inspect the page in chrome and toggle that field, (on or off, doesn't matter), the animation works properly for a few seconds only.

I'm not sure what would cause this, but any help would be appreciated.

```
.square0 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  -moz-transition: background-color 21s cubic-bezier(0, 1.31, .51, 1.05);
  -o-transition: background-color 21s cubic-bezier(0, 1.31, .51, 1.05);
  -ms-transition: background-color 21s cubic-bezier(0, 1.31, .51, 1.05);
  transition: background-color 21s cubic-bezier(0, 1.31, .51, 1.05);
}

.square0:hover {
  background-color: rgb(178, 49, 108);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked with me without any problem. Check out the snippet in chrome browser.

```css
 .square0 {
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 float: left;
 background-color: #eee;
 -moz-transition: background-color 21s cubic-bezier(0, 1.31, .51, 1.05);
 -o-transition: background-color 21s cubic-bezier(0, 1.31, .51, 1.05);
 -ms-transition: background-color 21s cubic-bezier(0, 1.31, .51, 1.05);
 transition: background-color 21s cubic-bezier(0, 1.31, .51, 1.05);
 }
 .square0:hover {
 background-color: rgb(178, 49, 108);
 }
```

```html
 <div class="square0"></div>
```

Comment: It still doesn't behave the way it should on my end. This is a screencap of the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCL44L-ATXA